# The name 'c' does not exist in the current context using OpenXml-sdk and C# for accessing Word file

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am using c# and open xml sdk 2.0 for accessing Word file after upload on the server.

I want to retrieve a chapter and paragraph based on the given text.

The chapters are insert on the table `chapter`

The chapters and paragraphs are insert on the table chapter `subheading`

Using `System.Linq` I can locate chapters `Contains Chapter`

```
foreach (Paragraph c in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(c => c.InnerText.Contains("Chapter")))
```

and subheading `Starts With "- "`

```
foreach (Paragraph p in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.StartsWith("- ")))
```

But I have this blocking error when get Visual Studio debug

```
CS0103: The name 'c' does not exist in the current context
```

Please help me

My code below

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile && FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var allowedExtensions = new string[] { "docx" };
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower().Replace(".", "");

            if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);

                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("public/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                file = Server.MapPath("public/") + filename;

                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
                {
                    body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    paras = "";

                    foreach (Paragraph c in
                        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(c => c.InnerText.Contains("Chapter")))
                    {
                        paras += c.InnerText + "<br/>";

                        strSql = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO Chapters (chapter) VALUES (?);";

                        using (MySqlConnection conn =
                            new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                                new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", c.InnerText);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }


                    foreach (Paragraph p in
                            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.StartsWith("- ")))
                    {
                        foreach (Run r in p.Descendants<Run>())
                        {
                            RunProperties rProp = r.RunProperties;

                            if (rProp.Bold != null)
                            {
                                paras += p.InnerText + "<br/>";

                                strSql = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO subheading (subheading, chapter) VALUES (?,?);";

                                using (MySqlConnection conn =
                                    new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                                {
                                    conn.Open();
                                    using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                                        new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
                                    {
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", p.InnerText);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", c.InnerText);
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    conn.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only DOCX files are accepted!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**edit #1**

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile && FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var allowedExtensions = new string[] { "docx" };
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower().Replace(".", "");

            if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);

                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("public/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                file = Server.MapPath("public/") + filename;

                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
                {
                    body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    paras = "";

                    foreach (Paragraph c in
                        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(somethingElse => somethingElse.InnerText.Contains("Sezione")))
                    {
                        paras += c.InnerText + "<br/>";

                        strSql = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO Chapters (chapter) VALUES (?);";

                        using (MySqlConnection conn =
                            new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                                new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", c.InnerText);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            conn.Close();
                        }



                        foreach (Paragraph p in
                                wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(somethingElse => somethingElse.InnerText.StartsWith("- ")))
                        {
                            foreach (Run r in p.Descendants<Run>())
                            {
                                RunProperties rProp = r.RunProperties;

                                if (rProp.Bold != null)
                                {
                                    paras += p.InnerText + "<br/>";

                                    strSql = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO subheading (subheading, chapter) VALUES (? ,?);"; //

                                    using (MySqlConnection conn =
                                        new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                                    {
                                        conn.Open();
                                        using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                                            new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
                                        {
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", p.InnerText);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", c.InnerText);
                                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        }
                                        conn.Close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Response.Write(paras);
                    }
                    Response.Write(paras);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only DOCX files are accepted!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're declaring `c` twice: `foreach (Paragraph c ` and `c => c.InnerText.Contains`. Change `c => c.InnerText.Contains` to `somethingElse => somethingElse.InnerText.Contains`.

Comment: @John thanks for help. I have changed `c => c.InnerText.Contains` to `somethingElse => somethingElse.InnerText.Contains` but the error it's the same

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", c.InnerText);` -> `c.InnerText` is invalid because `c` doesn't exist (the previous `foreach` was already closed, if indentation is correct)

Comment: @Camilo I didn't notice that was a separate loop.

Comment: @John I'm used to scanning code quickly :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto okay thanks, how can i make sure to have the value of  `c` also in the second `foreach` ?  (indentation is correct)

Comment: That depends entirely on which `c` you want (is it the first, the last, every `c`, etc)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I need every `c` value for insert `c` value and `p` value on the table `subheading`. For each chapters I have one or more paragraphs

Comment: So you just need the second `foreach` *inside* the first one.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks I have tried your suggestion but on the table `subheading` in the column `chapter` is inserted the only value of first `chapter`... please see **edit #1** in the question...

Comment: The code *looks* OK to me... you'll need to debug and see what's going on there. You really should split that method in smaller methods so that it's easier to read too. And avoid so much indentation by reversing `if` conditions

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
       WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
{
    body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    contents = "";

    var reg = new Regex(@"^[...customize...]");

    foreach (Paragraph co in
                wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(somethingElse => reg.IsMatch(somethingElse.InnerText)))
    {
        subheading += co.InnerText + "<br />";

        strSql = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO subheading (subheading) VALUES (?);";

        using (MySqlConnection conn =
            new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", co.InnerText);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```